# Splitting a string and inserting new string

Tags: java, string

I am trying to split a string (text) in twain so that I can insert a new string between the two based on the position of a cursor represented by an underscore. I did these using substrings like so:

```
String before = text.substring(0, cursorPosition);
String after = text.substring(cursorPosition, text.length());
return before + "_" + after;
```

This works fine except when the cursor position is at a newline. In which case the "_" replaces the first character on the new line. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: As your code is now, the "_" will start the string when the cursor position is 0 but it shouldn't replace the first character.

Comment: If you are constantly modifying text, you should make that a StringBuffer. Then your replacement function can just be:
  text.setCharAt(cursorPosition, '_');

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there are two pieces of logic that need to be handled separately when the cursor appearing at the index `0` or `text.length() - 1`. So you could try this code:

```java
String before = text.substring(0, cursorPosition);
String after = text.substring(cursorPosition, text.length());
if (cursorPosition == 0) return "_" + text;
if (cursorPosition == text.length() - 1) return text + "_";
return before + "_" + after;`
```